# At least one object must implement IComparable. AsEnumerable() and Sum()

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum

I try to group multiple column on the `tbl.AsEnumerable()`,
I want to group cus, salesman, ppj and curr while the amt_base should be sum up.

Everything fine, 
but when i use `grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("amt_base"))` on the sum of the amt it shown *At least one object must implement IComparable.* errors on the `foreach ()`.

```
var results = from rows in tbl.AsEnumerable()
                              group rows by new
                              {
                                  cus = rows["cus"],
                                  salesman = rows["salesman"],
                                  ppj = rows["ppj"],
                                  curr = rows["curr"],

                              }into grp
                              orderby grp.Key
                              select new
                              {
                                  cus = grp.Key.cus,
                                  nm = grp.First()["nm"],
                                  salesman = grp.Key.salesman,
                                  ppj = grp.Key.ppj,
                                  curr = grp.Key.curr,
                                  amt_base = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("amt_base")),
                              };

                DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();
                tbl2.Columns.Add("cus");
                tbl2.Columns.Add("nm");
                tbl2.Columns.Add("salesman");
                tbl2.Columns.Add("ppj");
                tbl2.Columns.Add("curr");
                tbl2.Columns.Add("amt_base");

                decimal  tamt_base = 0;

                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    DataRow dr2 = tbl2.NewRow();
                    dr2["cus"] = item.cus;
                    dr2["nm"] = item.nm;
                    dr2["salesman"] = item.salesman;
                    dr2["ppj"] = item.ppj;
                    dr2["curr"] = item.curr;
                    dr2["amt_base"] = Math.Round(item.amt_base, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                    tbl2.Rows.Add(dr2);
                    tamt_base += item.amt_base;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't determine how to order the rows based on an anonymous type comprised of of 4 random columns. It needs to be able to compare each instance to the previous, which is usually done by having your class implement the `IComparable` interface... but you can't with an anonymous type.

Remove this:

```
orderby grp.Key
```

If you really need some sort of ordering, try using an individual field:

```
orderby grp.Key.cus
```